# React router - redirect using indexRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router with `routes` parameter:

```
const rootRoute = {
    component: App,
    childRoutes: createRoutes(store),
    indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/new-url') }
};
```

Here is the `Router` jsx part:

```
<Router
    history={hashHistory}
    routes={rootRoute}>
</Router>
```

The `indexRoute` is the line I was trying to add to make the redirect but it doesn't work.

Comment: @EQuimper everything works as expected besides the indexRouter, so I guess it's ok.

Comment: You can use the [`<IndexRedirect>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects) component.

Comment: @MingSoon - I need this as part of the `rootRoute = { }` object, do you have an example for this?

Comment: @Dekel did you try to add `path: '/'` to your `rootRoute`?

Comment: @MingSoon just did it before you commented and it works! I was actually going to put this as an answer, but you are welcome to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `path: '/'` to your `rootRoute`.

Comment: Any chance of explaining this solution? Why it doesn't work without the `path`?

Comment: I think without the `path` config, the router doesn't know when to enter the `indexRoute`.

Comment: Just voted your answer, I'll accept it once possible.